# Logout when changing password in laravel using sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have implemented the admin panel. In the admin panel, the administrator can change passwords for users. How can I log out of the user whose password has been changed? Log out of all sessions.

I have tried changing user:

```
$current_user = auth('web')->getUser(); // or Auth::guard('web')->getUser(); 
Auth::guard('web')->setUser($user)
Auth::guard('web')->logout();
Auth::guard('web')->setUser($current_user);
```

But this method, the system re-authorizes me as the user to whom the password was changed.

if I use `auth()`, I get an error:

> Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::getUser does not exist.

`Kernel.php`:

```php
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
  'web' => [
    EncryptCookies::class,
    AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    StartSession::class,
    AuthenticateSession::class,
    VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    SubstituteBindings::class,
  ],

  'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    SubstituteBindings::class,
  ],
];
```

How can I solve this problem?